# Xgboost : A variable specific Feature importance

Tags: machine-learning, python, classification, xgboost, features

I have a data set something like this:

```
data = [['Alex',10,13,1,0],['Bob',11,14,12,0],['Clarke',13,15,13,1],['bob',12,15,1,1]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns = ["dealer","x","y","z","loss"])
```

I am trying to predict binary column loss, I have done this **xgboost** model. I got Overall feature importance. Now I need t**op 5 most important features dealer wise**.

How to do that?

I have tried to use **lime package** but it is only working for Random forest.

If I get Feature importance for **each observation(row)** then also I can compute the feature importance dealer wise.

kindly help

Desired Output :
[image]

Comment: Are you looking for which of the dealer categories is most predictive of a loss=1 over the entire dataset? In the example above dealer is text which makes it categorical and you handled that somehow which is not explained above.

Comment: @Craig I have edited the question. I am looking for Dealer-wise most important variables  which is helping me predict loss.

Comment: You should create 3 datasets sliced on Dealer. Then get the FI for each feature. This seems the only meaningful approach.

Comment: cross-posted at https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/503861/232706

Comment: @10xAI You mean to say i need to build multiple models ? as I have really less data I am not able to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a per-observation explanation, you could just average (or aggregate in some other way) the importances of features across the samples for each `Dealer`.

---

For example, using `shap` to generate the per-observation explanation:

```py
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
import shap

data = [['Alex',10,13,1,0],['Bob',11,14,12,0],['Clarke',13,15,13,1],['Bob',12,15,1,1]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["dealer","x","y","z","loss"])

lr = LogisticRegression()
lr.fit(df[['x', 'y', 'z']], df['loss'])

# Whatever explainer you prefer:
explainer = shap.explainers.Permutation(lr.predict_proba, df[['x', 'y', 'z']])
shap_values = explainer(df[['x', 'y', 'z']])

# get just the explanations for the positive class
shap_values = shap_values[...,1]

shap_df = pd.DataFrame(abs(shap_values.values))
shap_df.columns = ['x_shap', 'y_shap', 'z_shap']
shap_df['dealer'] = df['dealer']
shap_df.groupby('dealer').mean()
```

produces

| dealer | x_shap | y_shap | z_shap |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alex | 0.260427 | 0.140054 | 0.075176 |
| Bob | 0.106593 | 0.069035 | 0.091146 |
| Clarke | 0.268328 | 0.083706 | 0.085807 |

Comment: Hey, do you have any example of shap per observation explanation as I saw that first but i couldn't find any example on that.

Comment: Thanks This helped a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is -
*"When Dealer is X, how important is each Feature."*

*You can try [Permutation Importance](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/permutation_importance.html#permutation-importance).*

- Can be used on fitted model
- It is Model agnostic
- Can be done for Test data too.

Slice X, Y in parts based on *Dealer* and get the Importance separately.

Shown for California Housing Data on *Ocean_Proximity* feature

```py
from sklearn.inspection import permutation_importance

for val in x_train.ocean_proximity.unique():        # Loop on column value
    x = x_train.loc[x_train.ocean_proximity==val,:] # Slices X
    y = y_train.loc[x_train.ocean_proximity==val]   # Slices Y
    
    result = permutation_importance(model, x, y, n_repeats=5, random_state=0)
    result = pd.DataFrame(result.importances_mean, index= cols)
    
    # print, sorted top 4 Features
    print('Ocean--',val,result.sort_values(by=0,ascending=False)[:4])
```

**Note** - *The importance value for each feature with this test and "Impurity decreased" approach are not comparable.*